# pjsip pjsua USB SoundCard choopy

Tags: audio, alsa, pjsip, openwrt, speex

the pjsua runs in openwrt, we use USB SoundCard.
When we answer a call, allways choopy, both the capture and the playback are not work well!
Tips:We have use auddemo tested my soundcard, recoreding/playing are good, and the capture id is 8, playback id is 1.
thank you~~

below is logs:

```
11:58:06.357    dlg0xdb687c  .Received Request msg ACK/cseq=103 (rdata0xdb3ecc)
11:58:06.360   strm0xe038dc !Start talksprut..
11:58:06.361          speex  warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:06.363     alsa_dev.c  pb_thread_func: underrun!
11:58:06.587   Master/sound !160 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1888
11:58:06.587   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 2048 to 1888 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:06.588     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:06.756     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:06.968   Master/sound  228 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1980
11:58:06.968   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 2208 to 1980 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:06.968     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:06.981          speex  warning: No playback frame available (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:07.083   Master/sound  317 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1983
11:58:07.083     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:07.098          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:07.321   Master/sound !280 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1703
11:58:07.321   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1983 to 1703 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:07.321     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:07.493     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:07.505          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:07.707   Master/sound !182 samples reduced, buf_cnt=2161
11:58:07.711     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:07.506     alsa_dev.c !pb_thread_func: underrun!
11:58:07.936   Master/sound !376 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1785
11:58:07.937   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 2161 to 1785 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:07.937     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:07.950          speex  warning: No playback frame available (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:08.001          speex  warning: No playback frame available (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:08.099   Master/sound  467 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1958
11:58:08.100     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:08.108          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:08.331   Master/sound !390 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1568
11:58:08.332   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1958 to 1568 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:08.332     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:08.508     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:08.521          speex  warning: No playback frame available (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:08.574          speex  warning: No playback frame available (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:08.677   Master/sound  320 samples reduced, buf_cnt=2208
11:58:08.677     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:08.688          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:08.915   Master/sound !499 samples reduced, buf_cnt=2029
11:58:08.915     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:09.128   Master/sound  193 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1836
11:58:09.128   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 2029 to 1836 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:09.129     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:09.142          speex  warning: No playback frame available (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:09.197          speex  warning: No playback frame available (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:09.300   Master/sound  257 samples reduced, buf_cnt=2219
11:58:09.300     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:09.308          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:09.309     alsa_dev.c  pb_thread_func: underrun!
11:58:09.523   Master/sound !427 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1792
11:58:09.523   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 2219 to 1792 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:09.523     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:09.718     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:09.731          speex  warning: No playback frame available (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:09.832   Master/sound  297 samples reduced, buf_cnt=2135
11:58:09.833     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:09.845          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:10.080   Master/sound !160 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1975
11:58:10.080   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 2135 to 1975 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:10.080     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:10.316   Master/sound  110 samples reduced, buf_cnt=2185
11:58:10.316     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:10.329          speex  warning: No playback frame available (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:10.427   Master/sound  527 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1978
11:58:10.427          speex  warning: No playback frame available (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:10.530   Master/sound  142 samples reduced, buf_cnt=2156
11:58:10.531     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:10.538          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:10.768   Master/sound !169 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1987
11:58:10.768   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 2156 to 1987 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:10.769     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:11.004   Master/sound  67 samples reduced, buf_cnt=2240
11:58:11.005     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:11.017          speex  warning: No playback frame available (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:11.117   Master/sound  439 samples reduced, buf_cnt=2121
11:58:11.118     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:11.124          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:11.125     alsa_dev.c  pb_thread_func: underrun!
11:58:11.349   Master/sound !162 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1959
11:58:11.349   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 2121 to 1959 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:11.349     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:11.574   Master/sound  39 samples reduced, buf_cnt=2240
11:58:11.575     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:11.584          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:11.809   Master/sound !423 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1817
11:58:11.810   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 2240 to 1817 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:11.810     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:11.984     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:11.998          speex  warning: No playback frame available (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:12.106   Master/sound  224 samples reduced, buf_cnt=2233
11:58:12.106     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:12.115          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:12.328   Master/sound !295 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1938
11:58:12.329   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 2233 to 1938 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:12.329     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:12.564   Master/sound  31 samples reduced, buf_cnt=2227
11:58:12.565     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:12.573          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:12.574     alsa_dev.c  pb_thread_func: underrun!
11:58:12.803   Master/sound !368 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1859
11:58:12.804   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 2227 to 1859 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:12.804     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:12.990     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:13.002          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:13.223   Master/sound !568 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1931
11:58:13.223     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:13.469   Master/sound  416 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1515
11:58:13.469   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1931 to 1515 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:13.470     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:13.474          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:13.658     alsa_dev.c !ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:13.826     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:13.833          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:13.834     alsa_dev.c  pb_thread_func: underrun!
11:58:14.041   Master/sound !450 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1385
11:58:14.041   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1835 to 1385 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:14.041     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:14.216     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:14.223          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:14.433   Master/sound !169 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1536
11:58:14.434   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1705 to 1536 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:14.434     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:14.606     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:14.613          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:14.843   Master/sound !459 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1397
11:58:14.843   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1856 to 1397 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:14.844     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:15.023     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:15.032          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:15.033     alsa_dev.c  pb_thread_func: underrun!
11:58:15.254   Master/sound !454 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1263
11:58:15.254   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1717 to 1263 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:15.254     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:15.448     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:15.455          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:15.636     alsa_dev.c !ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:15.808     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:15.814          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:16.029   Master/sound !300 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1603
11:58:16.030   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1903 to 1603 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:16.030     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:16.195     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:16.204          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:16.205     alsa_dev.c  pb_thread_func: underrun!
11:58:16.429   Master/sound !369 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1554
11:58:16.430   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1923 to 1554 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:16.430     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:16.609     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:16.617          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:16.851   Master/sound !399 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1475
11:58:16.851   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1874 to 1475 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:16.852     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:17.037     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:17.047          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:17.268   Master/sound !461 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1334
11:58:17.268   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1795 to 1334 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:17.269     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:17.460     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:17.469          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:17.470     alsa_dev.c  pb_thread_func: underrun!
11:58:17.681   Master/sound !215 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1439
11:58:17.681   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1654 to 1439 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:17.682     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:17.859     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:17.867          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:18.089   Master/sound !350 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1409
11:58:18.089   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1759 to 1409 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:18.089     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:18.274     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:18.284          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:18.511   Master/sound !254 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1475
11:58:18.511   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1729 to 1475 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:18.512     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:18.514    pjsua_acc.c !Sending 2 bytes keep-alive packet for acc 1 to 211.149.184.241:5060
11:58:18.515   tdta0xe088f8  Destroying txdata raw
11:58:18.689     alsa_dev.c !ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:18.701          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:18.881     alsa_dev.c !ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:18.888     alsa_dev.c !pb_thread_func: underrun!
11:58:19.105   Master/sound !283 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1832
11:58:19.105   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 2115 to 1832 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:19.105     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:19.114          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:19.342   Master/sound !414 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1418
11:58:19.343   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1832 to 1418 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:19.343     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:19.517     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:19.526          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:19.736   Master/sound !173 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1565
11:58:19.736   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1738 to 1565 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:19.736     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:19.924     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:19.935          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:19.936     alsa_dev.c  pb_thread_func: underrun!
11:58:20.115     alsa_dev.c !ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:20.132   strm0xe038dc !VAD re-enabled
11:58:20.331   Master/sound !460 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1745
11:58:20.337   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 2205 to 1745 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:20.337     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:20.339   strm0xe038dc !Starting silence
11:58:20.340          speex  warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:20.574   Master/sound !387 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1358
11:58:20.574   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1745 to 1358 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:20.574     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:20.760     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:20.762    tsx0xdf545c !Timeout timer event
11:58:20.762    tsx0xdf545c  .State changed from Completed to Terminated, event=TIMER
11:58:20.765    tsx0xdf545c  Timeout timer event
11:58:20.765    tsx0xdf545c  .State changed from Terminated to Destroyed, event=TIMER
11:58:20.766   tdta0xdf43f0  ..Destroying txdata Response msg 200/NOTIFY/cseq=102 (tdta0xdf43f0)
11:58:20.766    tsx0xdf545c  Transaction destroyed!
11:58:20.948     alsa_dev.c !ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:20.958          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:20.960     alsa_dev.c  pb_thread_func: underrun!
11:58:21.187   Master/sound !295 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1383
11:58:21.187   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1678 to 1383 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:21.187     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:21.378     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:21.387          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:21.610   Master/sound !419 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1284
11:58:21.610   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1703 to 1284 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:21.612     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:21.804     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:21.810          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:22.040   Master/sound !168 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1436
11:58:22.040   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1604 to 1436 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:22.040     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:22.053     alsa_dev.c !pb_thread_func: underrun!
11:58:22.230     alsa_dev.c !ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:22.414          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:22.440     alsa_dev.c !ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:22.619     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:22.805     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:22.815     alsa_dev.c !pb_thread_func: underrun!
11:58:23.039   Master/sound !232 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1524
11:58:23.039   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1756 to 1524 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:23.039     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:23.229     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:23.237          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:23.470   Master/sound !341 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1503
11:58:23.470   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1844 to 1503 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:23.471     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:23.645     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:23.652          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:23.860   Master/sound !167 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1656
11:58:23.861   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1823 to 1656 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:23.861     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:24.049     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:24.056          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:24.057     alsa_dev.c  pb_thread_func: underrun!
11:58:24.267   Master/sound !166 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1810
11:58:24.267   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1976 to 1810 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:24.268     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:24.505   Master/sound  450 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1360
11:58:24.505   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1810 to 1360 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:24.505     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:24.697     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:24.708          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:24.883     alsa_dev.c !ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:25.121   Master/sound  209 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1791
11:58:25.121   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 2000 to 1791 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:25.122     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:25.132          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:25.133     alsa_dev.c  pb_thread_func: underrun!
11:58:25.354   Master/sound !319 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1472
11:58:25.354   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1791 to 1472 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:25.354     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:25.547     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:25.557          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:25.790   Master/sound !320 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1472
11:58:25.791   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1792 to 1472 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:25.791     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:25.982     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:25.990          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:26.218   Master/sound !201 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1591
11:58:26.218   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1792 to 1591 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:26.218     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:26.419          speex !warning: Auto-filling the buffer (your application is buggy and/or got xruns)
11:58:26.422     alsa_dev.c !ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:26.424     alsa_dev.c !pb_thread_func: underrun!
11:58:26.643   Master/sound !275 samples reduced, buf_cnt=1636
11:58:26.644   Master/sound  Buffer size adjusted from 1911 to 1636 (eff_cnt=1280)
11:58:26.644     alsa_dev.c  ca_thread_func: overrun!
11:58:26.646 sip_endpoint.c !Processing incoming message: Request msg INVITE/cseq=104 (rdata0xdb3ecc)
11:58:26.646   pjsua_core.c  .RX 841 bytes Request msg INVITE/cseq=104 (rdata0xdb3ecc) from UDP 211.149.184.241:5060:
INVITE sip:192.168.199.246:30003 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 211.149.184.241:5060;branch=z9hG4bK0ed27c3d;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:103009844960152@211.149.184.241>;tag=as47643774
To: <sip:8002@192.168.199.246:30003;ob>;tag=d7d7f583-6390-4a16-9b9c-2f35c8bef97f
Contact: <sip:103009844960152@211.149.184.241:5060>
Call-ID: 356bbaf75eabf6633e02135d7019b2e8@211.149.184.241:5060
CSeq: 104 INVITE
User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 11.7.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Supported: replaces, timer
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 238
```

Answer (score 0):

Beforte I compling simple_pjsua.c I set the log level frome 4 to 5.After complied and I run it, I fond the same warnging as you, but have no effect to the session.when I set the log level from 5 back to 4,the waring disappeared.I didn't know the reasion that cause the waring but I know it dosn't have effect to the session.